# sql query for 3 table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `users`, `teams`, and `users_teams` (as a middle table) like this:

**users:**

```
user_id
user_fullname
...
```

**users_teams:**

```
ut_user_id
ut_team_id
```

**teams:**

```
team_id
team_name
```

each user can be assigned to multiple teams.

Now I want to write a `SQL` query that returns the user and his/her teams like this:

```
user=[
        user_id: 1,
        user_fullname: 'user 1',
        teams: [
           0: [ team_id: 1, ...],
           1: [ team_id: 2, ...],
        ]
]
```

I mean I want to get the teams inside the user array (without use PHP)(with SQL query). How I can do this?

Comment: I am unaware of a way to achieve this without reformatting the result set with PHP. A database row, when fetched as an associative array, cannot build a nested array.

Comment: you can't get that result from SQL directly. Fetch the data from SQL in table format (which is the only way it can do it) and if you need some more complex structure, you'll need to write PHP code to create that.